# kivy reference text of TextInput by StringProperty

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I would like to get the text of my TextInput via a StringProperty, but it does not work. I get an empty string. In the second example, I am declaring the whole TextInput as an ObjectProperty and then it does work. What is wrong with my first example?

## How can a StringProperty be used to define the text inside a TextInput?

**First example does not print text of TextInput**
example1.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<rootwi>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        on_press: root.print_txt()
    TextInput:
        text: root.textinputtext
""")
class rootwi(BoxLayout):
    textinputtext = StringProperty()

    def print_txt(self):
        print(self.textinputtext)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return rootwi()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**Second example does print text of TextInput, but uses a ObjectProperty not StringProperty** example2.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock


Builder.load_string("""
<rootwi>:
    txt: txt
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        on_press: root.print_txt()
    TextInput:
        id: txt
""")
class rootwi(BoxLayout):
    txt = ObjectProperty()

    def print_txt(self):
        print(self.txt.text)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return rootwi()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**If I set the text to sth specific, it shows up in the TextInput.** (But still, cannot be printed)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<rootwi>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        on_press: root.print_txt()
    TextInput:
        text: root.textinputtext
""")
class rootwi(BoxLayout):
    textinputtext = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.textinputtext = 'palim'
        super(rootwi, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def print_txt(self):
        print(self.textinputtext)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return rootwi()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Why do not you use the `TextInput.text` attribute directly?

Comment: because this is a simplified example of a widget which is made up of multiple textinputs, labels, buttons all defined in the kv file. Normally I would stick to the second version, but I just do not get why I cannot work with the first one.

Comment: With `text: root.textinputtext` the text of the `TextInput` changes if the value of the `StringVariable` does,  but not vice versa.

Comment: yes, I saw that as well, for example if you specify it in the init method to be a certain value, it will be there if you start the app.

Comment: Maybe you need to do some sort of binding. (I added what you pointed out to the question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want set and get the text using the StringProperty then you should create a bidirectional  bind:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


Builder.load_string("""
<rootwi>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    textinputtext: txt.text
    Button:
        on_press: root.print_txt()
    TextInput:
        id: txt
        text: root.textinputtext
""")

class rootwi(BoxLayout):
    textinputtext = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(rootwi, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.textinputtext = 'palim'

    def print_txt(self):
        print(self.textinputtext)



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return rootwi()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That is a really nice answer.